Gatling Websocket Load Test
Hello I have a websocket server for a text game. The server works, I'm using it with a JS client and have also used it with Postman. At the moment I'm trying to perform a load test using Gatling Websocket API but without any success.
Upon connecting to the server it sends a message prompting for a selection (1 or 2). What I'm trying to do is to receive that message and send a "2" right after and keep the connection hanging.
The simulation code looks like this:
package computerdatabase;

import static io.gatling.javaapi.core.CoreDsl.*;
import static io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.*;

import io.gatling.javaapi.core.*;
import io.gatling.javaapi.http.*;

public class WebsocketSimulation extends Simulation {

    HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
            .wsBaseUrl("ws://localhost:5000");


    ScenarioBuilder scene = scenario("Websocket")
            .exec(ws("connect")
                    .connect("")
                    .await(30).on(ws.checkTextMessage("checkMessage")
                            .check(regex(".*?").saveAs("message")))
                    )
                .exec(session -> {
                System.out.println("response: " + session.get("message"));
                return session;
            })
            .exec(ws("sendMessage").sendText("2"))
            .pause(30)
            .exec(ws("Close WS").close());


    {
        setUp(scene.injectOpen(
                        atOnceUsers(1))
                .protocols(httpProtocol));
    }
}

Setting <root level="DEBUG"> in logback.xml, shows that the message is received in Gatling, however the session.get("response") returns nothing. And while the logs say that the message containing 2 is sent, the server never receives it.
Gatling's logs:
03:51:01.522 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.WsListener - Received response to WebSocket CONNECT: 101 Switching Protocols DefaultHttpHeaders[Upgrade: websocket, Connection: Upgrade, Sec-WebSocket-Accept: Bhe1yEfgK701lLdh9BK4+ZVDr4k=, Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_no_context_takeover; server_max_window_bits=12; client_max_window_bits=12, Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2024 01:51:01 GMT, Server: Python/3.11 websockets/13.1, content-length: 0]
03:51:01.527 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsConnectingState - Connected, performing checks before proceeding (no onConnected action)
03:51:01.528 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsFsm - Timeout 1437022170 scheduled
03:51:03.529 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 895, cap: 895, components=1))
03:51:03.533 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.ansi2html-content { display: inline; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
.body_foreground { color: #AAAAAA; }
.body_background { background-color: #000000; }
.inv_foreground { color: #000000; }
.inv_background { background-color: #AAAAAA; }
.ansi1 { font-weight: bold; }
.ansi2 { font-weight: lighter; }
.ansi37 { color: #F5F1DE; }
</style>
</head>
<body class="body_foreground body_background" style="font-size: normal;" >
<pre class="ansi2html-content">
<span class="ansi2"></span><span class="ansi1"></span><span class="ansi1 ansi37">Welcome to the Script!
Which mode would you like to play?
1.Single Player
2.Multi Player</span>
</pre>
</body>

</html>

03:51:03.544 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
03:51:03.544 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check sequence complete
03:51:03.544 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsFsm - Timeout 1437022170 cancelled
03:51:03.544 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Check sequences completed successfully
response: 
03:51:03.548 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.WsSendTextFrame - Sending text frame 2 with WebSocket '<function1>': Scenario 'Websocket', UserId #1
03:51:03.550 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Send text frame sendMessage 2
03:51:03.550 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - ctx.write msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 1, cap: 64))
03:51:03.553 [DEBUG] i.g.c.a.Pause - Pausing for 30000ms

================================================================================
2024-10-29 01:51:21 GMT                                      20s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3      KO=0     )
> connect                                                  (OK=1      KO=0     )
> checkMessage                                             (OK=1      KO=0     )
> sendMessage                                              (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Websocket -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done: 0     
================================================================================

03:51:21.517 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=PingWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 4, cap: 4))

================================================================================
2024-10-29 01:51:31 GMT                                      30s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=3      KO=0     )
> connect                                                  (OK=1      KO=0     )
> checkMessage                                             (OK=1      KO=0     )
> sendMessage                                              (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Websocket -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 1      / done: 0     
================================================================================

03:51:33.556 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.WsClose - Closing websocket '<function1>': Scenario 'Websocket', UserId #1
03:51:33.558 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Client requested WebSocket close
03:51:33.559 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsFsm - Timeout 2061203621 scheduled
03:51:33.560 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - ctx.write msg=CloseWebSocketFrame(data: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 5, cap: 64))
03:51:33.565 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=CloseWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 5, cap: 5))
03:51:33.570 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsFsm - Timeout 2061203621 cancelled
03:51:33.571 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsClosingState - Server has acked closing: 1000/Bye
03:51:33.573 [DEBUG] i.g.c.a.Exit - End user #1
03:51:33.578 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - End user #Websocket
03:51:33.579 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - channelInactive
03:51:33.579 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - All users of scenario Websocket are stopped
03:51:33.582 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - Stopping
03:51:33.583 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.Controller - Injector has stopped, initiating graceful stop

================================================================================
2024-10-29 01:51:33 GMT                                      32s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=4      KO=0     )
> connect                                                  (OK=1      KO=0     )
> checkMessage                                             (OK=1      KO=0     )
> sendMessage                                              (OK=1      KO=0     )
> Close WS                                                 (OK=1      KO=0     )

---- Websocket -----------------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done: 1     
================================================================================

03:51:33.598 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.Controller - StatsEngine was stopped
03:51:33.598 [INFO ] i.g.app.Runner - Simulation computerdatabase.WebsocketSimulation completed in 32 seconds

Any ideas what's wrong?

I’m surprised by the behavior you’re experiencing. I’ll check next week.
But your regex check is weird as it doesn’t contain a capture group. If your goal is to capture the full inbound message, just use a bodyString check. Otherwise, add a capture group.
